# Can I create a native MediaPlayer for Android api-10 (2.3.3)?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer

Can I create a native MediaPlayer for Android api-10 (2.3.3)?

I need it and I'm not finding anything less then api 14. I have an app that plays a video streaming from an rtsp connection, but the app is putting my CPU at 100% usage.  And I thought that the only way to made my app without doing that is using a native MediaPlayer. Am I thinking right? Where can I find something about that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).
It perfectly works on Android 2.3.3